# Select multiple checked values from dropdown and display those values with a textbox besides them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down with checkboxes besides it. First I want to add a search button in the dropdown. Second, once values are selected, a submit button on clicked should display the selected values with a textbox besides it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is not a place where you ask people to do something you need. This is a place where you ask for help regarding an issue you're facing with your code. Please provide some code or what you already tried and we wil see if we can help you in any way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checkboxes you could select with multiple option.

I would recommend you to use select2 library for your requirement.
It provides search box along with multiple value selection and different styles also which is very handy because it's very difficult to style option tag in html.

Find below the select2 url:
https://select2.org/getting-started/installation